# Swap text for an image with Jquery and rails

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So .. I have an application that saves posts as a favorite, currently clicking "Favorite" it makes the change without reloading the page for "Unfavorite", my question is how do I exchange the text for an image?

Helper

```
   def favorite_text
     return @favorite_exists ? "UnFavorite" : "Favorite"
   end
```

View

```
<%= link_to favorite_text, favorites_update_path(post: @post), id: 'favorite_link', remote: true %>
```

update.js

```
$('#favorite_link').text("<%= favorite_text %>");
```

Comment: You are making an AJAX call, correct? when you get the result back you can call `$('#favorite_link').text("<%= favorite_text %>");` so your text gets updated

Comment: ok, but how do i replace and "Favorite and Unfavorite" with one image, when i click on the image it should be replaced with a different image. I am a beginner and so I have many difficulties

Comment: posted an answer that might help. You made a few edits to your question in the mean time, but I think you will get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Modify your controller a little:

```
def favorite_text
  @favorite_text = @favorite_exists ? "UnFavorite" : "Favorite"
end
```

Then you need to create a view under your controller name like this: `favorite_text.js.erb`

This view will be called when your controller returns, so you need this to call the javascript code to update your code, you can do this to update the text and image:

```
$('#favorite_link').text("<%= @favorite_text %>");
$("#favorite_image").attr('src',"<%= @favorite_text %>.png");
```

Here I am assuming your images are named like the favorite/unfavorite text.

You can also use [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon) to share rails variables with javascript

Comment: Ok,  
in controller to change the text "Favorite", can I use the method like this image_tag ("my image.png")?
like that
@favorite_exists ? imag_tag ("UnFavorite.png"): image_tag ("Favorite.png")

Comment: @EduardoFrota if you want to do that you have to call the helper like this: `ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("image.png")`

Comment: I can't, can you help me build this method, at the moment mine is like this: `class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def favorite_text
    return @favorite_exists ? "UnFavorite" : "Favorite"
  end
  helper_method :favorite_text
end'`

Comment: Did you try what I wrote in the answer above?